# Executing a Python command with a setuid/setgid wrapper

Tags: python, c, setuid, execve

I have the following Python script that I'd like to execute with the permissions afforded by the setuid/setgid bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from mypackage.cli import main as cli_main
cli_main()
```

**However:** I would like execute the command directly from a C wrapper without an intermediate Python script file.

I've tried doing this using `execve` as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char *ENV = "/usr/bin/env";
const char *ENV_ARGS[] = { "python3", "-c", "from mypackage.cli import main as cli_main; cli_main()" };
const int NUM_ENV_ARGS = 3;

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    int total_num_args = (argc - 1) + NUM_ENV_ARGS + 1;

    // Create an array of strings to hold the final arg list.
    // No need to free the malloc'ed memory as it will be freed if execve succeeds,
    // or when the program exits if execve fails.
    char **final_args = (char **)malloc(total_num_args * sizeof(char *));
    if (final_args == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Copy the invocation and the arguments to this program into the final arg list.
    memcpy(final_args, ENV_ARGS, NUM_ENV_ARGS * sizeof(char *));
    memcpy(final_args + NUM_ENV_ARGS, argv + 1, (argc - 1) * sizeof(char *));
    final_args[total_num_args - 1] = NULL;

    return execve(ENV, final_args, envp);
}
```

But I get the following error when I run the compiled program as `./mycli foo bar`:

```
python3: illegal option -- c
usage: env [-iv] [-P utilpath] [-S string] [-u name]
           [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `./mycli foo bar`. Same error occurs without any arguments though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing your argument array incorrectly.  It should correspond exactly to the exec'ed program's `argv` array, including that the 0<sup>th</sup> element designates the name of the program, which in this case would conventionally be "env" or "/usr/bin/env".  Because you skip the "env", `env` is interpreting "python3" as *its own* name, as evidenced by the error message.  That message comes from `env`, not from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You're not running the `python3` command.  You're running the `env` command.  The `ENV` variable should contain `/usr/bin/python3`, or whatever you path to `python3` is.

Comment: The environment variables are passed through from the caller to the `execve` call so `env` gets the same variables that it would have if I called it directly from the command line.

Comment: @DanielGibbs No, those environment variables are in`envp`.  There's no need to call `env`.

Comment: So what would I change to make it work? I'd like to use `env` as I can't guarantee where the `python3` executable is located.

Comment: @DanielGibbs if you know `python3` is on the path, just use `const char *ENV = "python3"`.  Then use `execvp`, which searches the path,  instead of `execve`.

Comment: "The other functions take the environment for the new process image from the external variable environ in the calling process." That must've been the bit I missed in the man page.